# Kettle spoon run in windows 10, always fails

Tags: pentaho, windows-10, kettle

When I add a hop between two steps, it always goes wrong.

```
一个未预期的错误发生在Spoon: probable cause:在停止Spoon前，请先关闭其它spoon窗口!
```

null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph.addHop(TransGraph.java:1537)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.trans.TransGraph$8.widgetSelected(TransGraph.java:1496)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1316)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7979)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9310)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:654)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

Comment: can you raise a Pentaho - JIRA ticket reg. this issue.? I assume it might be an issue with your installation or either windows10 is not compatible with the pentaho release. Not sure though.

Comment: Pentaho Spoon works on my Windows 10 desktop with JDK 1.7, So this might not be a Windows issue. Can you please post your JDK version and what kind of repository are you using?

Comment: See my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366024/unable-to-connect-steps-in-pentaho-pdi-installed-on-windows-10/32367079#32367079