# Unable to connect steps in Pentaho PDI installed on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, pentaho, pdi

I installed a fresh copy of Windows 10 (Education version)and discovered that when I run Pentaho PDI (version 5.4) that I am unable to connect two steps together. Normally there is a dialog window that opens where you can select the add hop but nothing.

I installed the JRE and JDK versions of Java. No other issues that I have nothing with other application using Java.

I did make the discovery this evening if I place two steps on the work surface and then attempt to execute the transformation, it fails like you except however now I can connect those two steps. Adding another step, you cannot connect until execute the script. Strange.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this issue?

Many thanks
Ray

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pentaho Data Integration and Pentaho Data Integration server are not currently supported for windows 10. Check [this](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.4/0D0/160/000) and this [JIRA ticket.](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-13626)